# v-select auto selection based on value not key

Tags: vue.js, v-select

my v-select items looks like below

```
{
        key: 'most_engaged',
        value: 'Most engaged'
    }, {
        key: '',
        value: 'Most recent'
    }, {
        key: 'desc',
        value: 'Most positive'
    }, {
        key: 'asc',
        value: 'Most negative'
    }, {
        key: 'most_engaged1',
        value: 'Most engaged'
    }
```

Ie I set 'most_engaged' item as default one, then all items with value 'Most Engaged' are selected.So how to resolve this issue?

My Exact requirement is preselection is based on key not value...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `item-text` and `item-value` props described here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#select
Then set a `v-model` to your default value like this:

````
<v-select
:items="myItems"
item-text="key"
item-value="value"
v-model="currentValue"
></v-select>
.
.
.
data(){
   return {
        currentValue: {  
           key: 'most_engaged',
           value: 'Most engaged'
    }
    ```
````